# R binomial family with identity link

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, link-function

I want to fit a linear model by R with `family=binomial(link="identity")`, however, binomial family do not have identity link. What should I do?

Comment: I think there's an underlying statistical issue here.

Comment: yes, the following question will ask about Adjust the standard error for overdispersion.

Comment: But for the first one, I need use the identity link in the binomial family, but R does not permit it.

Comment: My comment was addressed to people deciding whether or not to close as off topic; I was explaining my vote to leave it open. That a subsequent question will be statistical doesn't impact this question though, which at least on first glance appears to be merely about how to do something in R. A slight rephrase to address the directly statistical issue might make it more clearly on topic here.

Comment: Note that if you need to both deal with overdispersion *and* use an identity link you should consider going directly to a quasi- model with binomial variance function. An intercept-only binomial model can be fitted *by  hand*.

Comment: See Wikipedia on the [linear probability model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probability_model) & CV posts [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81789) & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104399) for the statistical background. You want `family=quasi(link="identity", variance = "mu(1-mu)")`, if you want it.

Comment: (And if you wanted the dispersion parameter fixed at one: `family=binomial(link=make.link("identity"))`.

Comment: @Scortchi, why not turn those comments into an official answer?

Comment: @gung: On actually testing the code before posting an answer I found out you don't need `make.link`.

Answer (score 11):

See Wikipedia on the [linear probability model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probability_model), & CV posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81789) & [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104399) for the statistical background. Though not "wrong", you'd want a good reason for using an identity link to model a Bernoulli probability.

According to the `family` manual

> the binomial family [accepts] the links `logit`, `probit`, `cauchit`,
>   (corresponding to logistic, normal and Cauchy CDFs respectively) `log`
>   and `cloglog` (complementary log-log)

But

> The link and variance arguments have rather awkward semantics for
>   back-compatibility. The recommended way is to supply them is as quoted
>   character strings, but they can also be supplied unquoted (as names or
>   expressions). In addition, they can also be supplied as a length-one
>   character vector giving the name of one of the options, or as a list
>   (for `link`, of class `"link-glm"`). The restrictions apply only to links
>   given as names: when given as a character string all the links known
>   to `make.link` are accepted.

So `family=binomial(link="identity")` works but `family=binomial(link=identity)` doesn't. (If you find differently it might be to do with the R version.) To allow for over-dispersion, then use`family=quasi(link="identity", variance = "mu(1-mu)")`.

Comment: the link="identity" vs. link=identity fix was a huge help. This is a workout in Agresti's CDA textbook. The code he provides is the quasi(link...) you discuss, however the simplicity of adding " " is elegant fix. To my understanding the link="identity" call represents the binomial as a linear model.