# Are there any reasons to use the identity link in logistic regression (or any other glm)?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, link-function

From this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140662/22199), the following statement is posed:
'*Though not "wrong", you'd want a good reason for using an identity link to model a Bernoulli probability.*'

I would like to know what good reasons would result in an identity link being used for logistic regression, if these exist. Do these reasons generalise to GLMs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I frequently use the identity link to model a Bernoulli probability when I want to obtain adjusted risk differences or just an adjusted risk.  If you wanted to obtain risk differences (e.g. $\hat{p_1}-\hat{p_2}$), and have no need to calculate odds ratios, this is the most straight forward way to calculate them.  See this paper for additional details:  http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/162/3/199.full

Logistic regression is a Generalized Linear Model.  It does generalize.

Comment: are these risk differences valid even if $\hat{p}_i$ are negative?

Comment: the paper does not make any sense to me. A concrete example would be really helpful, as I don't understand SAS code.

Comment: You shouldn't really need to understand the SAS to get the gist of this paper.  Plus, I already told you what it said (you can use it for adjusted risk-differences).  The authors simply show that they use an identity link with both a binomial and poisson regression to obtain adjusted risk ratios:  "By replacing link=log with link=identity in the MODEL statement, multivariate-adjusted risk (prevalence) differences are obtained as follows" . . . "

The model statements in SAS and R are nearly identical.  You shouldn't have any trouble reading the SAS model statement that follows the text above.

Comment: @Alex, how would you get a negative probability?  In logistic regression, $\hat{p}$ is restricted to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Doesn't the identity link imply a linear regression with likelihood calculated using the logistic distribution? How are probabilities restricted to 0 and 1 if you extrapolate using this model?

Comment: Hi, @Alex, sorry, I misunderstand your previous reference to $\hat{p}$ -- I thought you were using in the logistic regression context with a logit link.  Yes, using an identity link, you can indeed obtain risks that fall outside of 0 and 1 and the models can sometimes fail to converge.  There have been methods proposed on how to handle a situation when that occurs.

Comment: Also see:   See for example, http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/123/1/174.abstract?ijkey=41bfebc687e24e42ce530c04be6defe98fa983dc&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha and http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/166/11/1337.abstract?ijkey=f7b96993742bfe3161e3fdd88fb45a2aeefeae81&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha