# The identity link not used for binary response

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, link-function

Questions: The identity link is the standard one with normal responses but is not often used with binary or count responses. Why do you think this is?

My idea:  The range for a linear predictor, and the range of the identity link applied to a binomial probability or to a Poisson mean. I am kinda confused

Comment: It’s to map the real line to a range of plausible values of the parameter of the response distribution. Instead of $Poisson(-1)$, the $log$ link gives us $Poisson(e^{-1})$.

Comment: @Dave What do mean by Poisson(-1)?

Comment: See  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139917/r-binomial-family-with-identity-link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the identity link for the binary data, then your regression equation would be
$$
{\rm Pr}(Y_i|x_i)\equiv p_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i.
$$
Without any restriction on the coefficients, RHS can range in real-line (for example, a negative value). Since this does not make any sense for probability $p_i$, we transform it so that $g(p_i)$ takes its value in $[-\infty, \infty]$.