# How to fix violated linear probability model assumptions?

Tags: r, probability

I am currently conducting research on the experience of loneliness (1 = lonely, 0 = not) amongst Ethnic Groups. I have been advised to conduct the analysis using a linear probability model. I am aware that this violates many assumptions (non-normality, heteroscedastic errors, values lying outside 0,1). I understand that heteroscedasticity can be corrected by computing robust standard errors. But I was wondering if there was any way these violated assumptions can be corrected/minimised in the language r. For example, is there a way to produce valid predictions alongside this model? I feel if I present the corrected terms this will support my justification to use a linear probability model.

Comment: you prbably want logistic regression; a [ucla](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) link to get started

Comment: I am using survey weights so my sample size for some ethnic groups is less than 10, is this acceptable with a logistic regression model?

Answer (score 1):

> For example, is there a way to produce valid predictions alongside this model?

Yes, there is, and it is called *logistic regression*.  The details of logistic regression are too long to put here.  You can find them in any number of books on *Generalized Linear Models*.  Logistic regression fixes near all of the problems you've listed here:

- Non-normality is no problem because we model the likelihood (appropriately) as binomial rather than normal.
- Dependence of the variance on the mean is also naturally handled
- The logistic link function $\operatorname{logit} : \mathbb{R} \to (0,1)$, so we always get valid predictions.

The trade off is (perhaps) in interpretability.  Linear probability models are dead simple in their interpretation, but the coefficients of a logistic regression are in terms of *log odds ratios*.  Its simple to state what these are, but difficult to interpret them in the same way as the coefficients of a linear model.

LPM vs Logistic regression is hotly debated in some circles, and before progressing I think it may be beneficial to kindly ask whomever suggested LPM why they did that and not suggest logistic regression.

Comment: Does sample size affect the use of logistic regression? I am currently using the svyglm() package in r to compute my models as I am applying the correct survey weights. For one ethnic group, the application of survey weights means the sample size is reduced to 9 observations. However, I thought a rule of thumb for logistic regression was 10 observations per predictor? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I typically use 7 events per predictor, but this is questionable, as I say below. First of all, with binary outcomes, EVENTS per predictor matters: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5394463/ . Moreover, rules of thumb are subjective: https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-016-0267-3 : one should check whether, in their particular case, there's multicollinearity and quasi-separation:

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the usual "caveats" about the Linear Probability Model do not apply, in my opinion. The only issue I see is that you won't end up with odds ratios, but with risk differences. But this is not a problem at all: you can get the probabilities estimated by your model to estimate, in turn, both odds ratios and risk ratios. Generalized Linear Models (here is an example of a paper suggesting such approach, defining it as a "binomial model for the risk difference": https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/162/3/199/171116) may let you address
non-normality (that may be an issue for inference in small samples) and heteroskedasticity (here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140662/159259 you can see the formula to define the variance as a function of the mean in R). As for values lying outside the 0-1 interval: with a categorical predictor, you'll just have the point estimates of N probabilities (given by their frequencies), whose 1 will be the reference category (the constant term representing its estimated probability), while the N-1 parameters associated to all other ethnical groups will be their risk-difference estimates, wrt such reference category . All estimated probabilities will be strictly between 0 and 1, assuming that you wouldn't consider ethnical group as a variable in first place if all were from the same group, and that you wouldn't include any ethnical group that is not represented in your sample.